# WebVTT Roku subtitle

Tags: roku, webvtt

I am trying to play video in roku in hls format and I  Just wondering is there a way of setting a webvtt url as subtitle instead of embed it in the HLS stream?

Answer (score 0):

**This is from the Roku SDK docs:**

> WebVTT
>   Roku supports WebVTT captions if embedded in HLS streams or manifests. As with the other closed caption formats, a channel specifies WebVTT captions in the SubtitleTracks metadata. The TrackName property is set to "webvtt/track" where track specifies the index of the caption track to render.

So as far as I know, there is no other way of setting a webvtt.